# Deterministic Signing

Tags: rsa, signature, deterministic-encryption, trapdoor

A signature scheme has three algorithms (Kgen, Sign, Ver), Kgen is necessarily randomized
and Ver is ususally determinstic. Show that it is without loss of generality to restrict
the signing algorithm Sign to be deterministic. That is, show that given any secure
signature scheme (Kgen, Sign, Ver) with a randomized signing algorithm, one can turn
it into another secure signature scheme (Kgen'
, Sign'
, Ver'
) with a deterministic signing
algorithm. Write down your design rationale.

Hint: Use a PRF

Hint:You need to use Sign, your goal is that given an arbitrary randomized signing algorithm Sign, with Kgen and Ver.
turn them into another signature scheme (Kgen', Sign', Ver'), so that, Sign' is deterministic.

How in the hell does this make sense?? How do I take something random use and use it to make something deterministic. PLEASE HELP

Comment: How could a PRF bei used to always generate the same randomness for the same message, i.e., make signing deterministic?

Comment: The hint to use a PRF works rather directly if the signing algorithm uses a bounded amount of randomness (if it does not, use the PRF to build a PRNG). Notice that the proof of security of the deterministic signature scheme will assume that the adversary is bounded in the number of PRF evaluations she can do, thus in that sense the security assurance will be weaker than for the randomized scheme.